# Count multiple conditions - Power BI / DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data that looks like this (simplification to understand the problem):

[image]

And I need a measure to know: "The number of groups that have values in the two conditions"

In this case, the only group that fits is the group "A", so the count/result is: 1

- The group A have values in C2 and C1
- The group B have C2 but not C1
- The Group C has neither C1 or C2

How can I do that?
I hope I was clear, thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another method that checks that both `C1` and `C2` exist in rows with `Value = 1` for each `Group`.

```
CountBothConditions =
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Value] = 1 ),
        Table1[Group],
        "ExistsC1", "C1" IN VALUES ( Table1[Condition] ),
        "ExistsC2", "C2" IN VALUES ( Table1[Condition] )
    ),
    IF ( [ExistsC1] && [ExistsC2], 1, 0 )
)
```

Comment: Great. What if I need to know what group fits? (If I add the measure to the Table, show 1 in all the "A" and 0 in the rest)

Comment: This should already work to show 1 for "A" and 0 for "B". It will give a blank for C though since it's summing an empty table in that case. You can add `+ 0` to the end of the measure to change that.

Answer (score 2):

This measure should works as expected:

```
Groups without blanks = 
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( Table1[Group] ),
        CALCULATE ( 
            COUNTROWS ( Table1 ), 
            ISBLANK(Table1[Value])
        ) = 0
    )
)
```

Let me know if it helped you

Comment: The solution seems good, the problem is that is ignoring the Column condition and if in it may exists other groups (C3,C4,C5...) would not work